# How to return data to sender of a channel

Tags: http, go, channel

I am a Golang newbiew, and I am trying to implement an http server that synchronizes access to an ultra expensive computational (SAT) operation using a channel.

So I'd have these concurrent requests coming in, they'd pass their data to a channel, and a processing goroutine would pick up the data from the channel and perform the expensive operation, but after its done, what is the best way to return the result to the sender so the sender can send the http response?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Idiomatic way to make a request-response communication using channels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236827/idiomatic-way-to-make-a-request-response-communication-using-channels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27238300/55504) as well.

Channels are first class types in Go,
you can just include a "response" channel in the request itself.
E.g. something like:

```
type Request struct {
    Input int
    RespC chan *Responce
}

type Response struct {
    Result int
    Err    error
}
```

Service:

```
for req := range ReqC {
    // start go routine or whatever
    req.RespC <- &Result{Err: errors.New("not implemented")}
}
```

Requester:

```
c := make(chan *Response)
ReqC <- &Request{Input: 42, RespC: c}
res := <-c
// check res.Err, use res.Result
```

Where `Request` and `Response` can contain whatever fields you need.
If the structs are small (like this example) use `chan Response` instead of `chan *Response` (and the same for `Request`).

Comment: Thanks! This is actually what I did, but I was not sure if this is the right approach

Comment: It is 'a' right approach (but not the only one) and the obvious choice in this case. If you're mathematically interested, using channels is described by [CSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes), and exchange of channel-ends is covered by [Pi Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus).